# Control keys stopped working on laptop, then mapped key stopped working?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm having this weird issue with my windows 10 laptop. First **both** ctrl keys stopped working at the same time. It didn't happen suddenly though. First I had to tap them a dozen times before they started working, eventually they both died.

I used an external keyboard and the ctrl buttons worked so I wrote it off as a hardware issue. I decided to map the left alt button to the left ctrl button so I can still use shortcuts. It was working fine yesterday. Today, same issue. I had to tap it a few times before it started working, then it stopped.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue. Try reinstalling the driver and see if that helps.

Another test you could run to diagnose this would be to remap a different key (e.g. 'e') to the control key and see if it becomes responsive.